# Facebook API Share Dialogue requires App

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to create a nice little share dialogue for my website via Html link of Javascript.

I tried this using the FB JS Api and it worked nicely for developers
            $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '1398858600336450',
            });

```
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'qvtropicalretreatgame.com',
            name: 'QV Tropical Retreat',
            caption: 'Message in a bottle',
            description: "I've just played the QV Tropical game to go in the draw to win a luxe escape to the tropics valued at up to $5,000",
            picture: 'http://qvtropicalretreatgame.com/img/bottle.png',
            message: ''
        });
    });
```

[image]

However this won't work as the the app has not been approved and I've found it to be a very strenuous process to make this happen. It seems that an app must be a fully functional facebook game where I just want to gain the ability to allow users to share my WEBSITE to facebook. Is it possible to achieve with out an app_id?

Comment: Use the share dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog don't require login or any permissions

Comment: Sounds good but I won't be able to achieve add name, caption and description with this method will I? Can I get a snipit per chance?